Passing per-request Apache environment variables to Node app
I'm authenticating to Shibboleth IdP using Apache mod_shib and ProxyPass to access a Node application running NestJS. SAML attributes are released as environment variables (strongly preferred) or HTTP headers as configured. ProxyPass is capable of passing HTTP headers onto the Node app, and I was able to test this with success, but have not been successful in passing environment variables onto the Node app. I.e.:
This virtualhost configuration works as expected
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Location />
            AuthType shibboleth
            ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1
            ShibUseHeaders On
            Require shibboleth
            ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    </Location>
    <Location /Shibboleth.sso>
            ProxyPass !
            SetHandler shib
            AuthType None
            Require all granted
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>

But this does not, as YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME is undefined
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Location />
            SetEnv YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME "value"
            AuthType shibboleth
            ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1
            Require shibboleth
            ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    </Location>
    <Location /Shibboleth.sso>
            ProxyPass !
            SetHandler shib
            AuthType None
            Require all granted
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>

What is the expected configuration in this case?

replace SetEnv YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME "value" by        RequestHeader set X-Env-Var "your_environment_variable_value"

Yes, it seems what I'm asking for is impossible with Apache. Shibboleth documentation is adamant to recommend against using request headers to supply attribute values, but it seems to be a matter of making sure there are no loose ends, rather than being completely impractical. This article helped me:
https://github.security.telekom.com/2020/05/smuggling-http-headers-through-reverse-proxies.html
